# Make TextView auto fit in middle of views

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface, android-linearlayout, android-layout-weight

I'm making my app and im not able to achive this, I need to get the following:
[Layout that I need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWoIU.png)

The problem is that I need the part  **6: 01.33** to be in the left, the scramble (All the letters) In the middle and the buttons on the right.
I have try several things like using Weight but I'm still not able to achive this. I also try with relativeLayout but still nothing. I let you the code that I have done:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    app:cardBackgroundColor="?attr/cardBackgroundColor"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
   <LinearLayout
       android:weightSum="3"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:orientation="horizontal"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content">
       <TextView
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:padding="10dp"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:textColor="?attr/primaryTextColor"
           android:text="105: 46.23"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
       <TextView
           android:layout_weight="1.5"
           android:padding="10dp"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:textColor="?attr/secondaryTextColor"
           android:text="F2 R B L2 F R B L2 F R B2 L' R2 B F"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
       <LinearLayout
           android:layout_weight="0.5"
           android:orientation="horizontal"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content">

           <Button
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:background="@color/fui_transparent"
               android:text="+2"/>
           <Button
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:background="@color/fui_transparent"
               android:text="DNF"/>
       </LinearLayout>
   </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove

```
android:weightSum="3"
```

and all

```
android:layout_weight="xx"
```

and add

```
android:layout_weight="1"
```

to your scramble TextView should do the trick. Your first TextView should be on the left and the buttons right. The remaining space will be taken from your scramble TextView.

Answer (score 0):

Use RelativeLayout

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:id="@+id/leftView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:text="105: 46.23"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/midddleView"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/leftView"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/rightView"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:text="F2 R B L2 F R B L2 F R B2 L' R2 B F"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/rightView"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="+2"/>
                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="DNF"/>
            </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```